# About a limit-no l'hospital or derivatives

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, limits-without-lhopital

So i've come across this limit:

$\lim_{x\to1} x^{\cot{\pi x}}$

So i found that its possible to solve without using those before-mentioned tools. 
I'm not sure how to do this limit,while i get stuck at this:

$\lim_{x\to 1} x^{\frac{\cos{\pi x} { \pi x}}{sin{\pi x}{  \pi x}}}$

I know i have to change the variable,so that i will $\lim_{t\to\infty}....$ for the modified variable $t$,  but i am stuck at that part.
Thank you in advance. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Could expanding the power series of $e^{\cot (\pi x)\log x}$ help? Just a thought...

Comment: @picasso: Taylor is equivalent to L'Hospital.

Comment: @picasso wake up brain ! :-)

Comment: Well taylor is also out of possibilities..

Comment: @VincenzoOliva I do not think Taylor is equivalent to L'Hopital.

Comment: @zhw. Taylor's theorem is proved using L'Hôpital's rule, and L'Hôpital's rule can be proved using Taylor's theorem. This makes them equivalent. Plus, they both use successive derivatives.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take $t=1-x$ and rewrite the expression as $ \exp( \cot(\pi (1-t)) \log (1-t) )$. The cosine just tends to $-1$, so it all amounts to evaluating $$ \lim_{t\to 0} \exp \left( - \frac{\log (1-t) }{\sin (\pi (1-t) )} \right) =  \lim_{t\to 0} \exp \left( - \frac{\log (1-t) }{t} \frac{\sin t}{\sin (\pi (1-t) )} \right) = e^{1/\pi}, $$ where we have used two elementary limits.

Comment: Don't you think that these elementary limits and Taylor are very close to eachother ? I am serious here and I really should appreciate your opinion. Not being involved in any teaching, I always wonder if Taylor and asymptotics could not be teached before limits.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici: I think basic limits are more easily handled via "algebra of limits" and "the standard/elementary limits" like $\sin x/x \to 1$ as $ x\to 0$. But Taylor series which uses repeated differentiation sits at a somewhat higher level than these simple limit concepts. However the importance of Taylor is that you gain deeper insight into how fast / slow an expression tends to its limit. Even I am not into teaching, but I believe presenting Taylor (with proof) to an average 16-17 year old student would be difficult compared to giving him "algebra of limits"

Comment: @ParamanandSingh. Thanks for giving your point of view. But what you point is exactly my problem. At what time do we need to switch from simple limit concepts to something more advanced ? When I was young (looong time ago), we were explained series expansion quite very early and never just asked *what is the limit ?* but *what is the limit and how is it approached ?*. At the beginning, I flet it was hard but very quickly I changed my mind. So, I really wonder how I should teach this topics if I had to. Cheers :-)

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici: I suppose you should put that as a question on MSE with "education" tag. I am not competent enough to judge the teaching methodologies. Perhaps we can get some good feedback from other people on MSE.

Comment: On the elementary limits: how are these known without reference to derivatives?

Comment: They are just used for easier solving. Mainly not proven. Just taken for granted.

Comment: @user246608 Not really. The trigonometric one has a geometric squeezing proof, not involving derivatives. The logarithmic one follows from the binomial theorem, since $$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\log(1+bx)}{x}=\log\left(\lim_{x\to0}\left(1+bx\right)^{1/x}\right)\overbrace{=}^{y=1/x}\log\left(\lim_{y\to\infty} \left(1+\frac{b}{y}\right)^y \right).$$

Comment: @zhw. And while the binomial expansion looks the same as a Taylor series, it is not hard to conjecture the general form (with integer $y$) and then prove it by induction. Since we know the limit exists, all subsequences converge to the limit that we found with integer $y$.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici: Thanks for your interest, I like the topic. Sorry, I'm outdoors, now I need to go out, I'll answer you as soon as I can.

Comment: Well i was talking of my experience since this is my first year of math in college,so we did prove some of those elememtary limits, but not all of them.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici:I recognize that elementary limits essentially derive from first or second order truncations of Taylor expansions. However, my point was that these two have also different arguments.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici: Regarding your problem, I believe it is not inconceivable to introduce Taylor relatively early. In particular, it seems to me that many students try to approximate the square root with a (finite) polynomial, so the introduction may well start from there. Furthermore, one often hears in class "Why are we doing this stuff? What's the point of computing limits?"; well, I reckon Taylor would be of help in this matter, besides providing a more deeply understanding of the subject.

Comment: @user246608: Yes, of course.

Comment: @VincenzoOliva. Thanks for your answer. May be the problem is how are things presented to the students and how the shuld be..

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici: As far as I'm concerned, no doubt about that. And to me, a ludic and thoroughly explanatory approach is the answer.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici: May I ask what did you study at the Politecnico? :) Next month I'll go study to the State University of Milan, but I did sit for a test in the Politecnico, which I discarted as it would have offered me engeneering mathematics, not in my interests.

Comment: @VincenzoOliva. I have been giving lectures in the area of thermodynamics and quantum chemistry there as visiting professor (in 1970 and 1974). Did you check my age ? Good luck for your studies.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici: Ohhh, I see, I misunderstood you yesterday; I thought you were even younger when you went there. Anyway, that's great of you! I didn't check your age: you say you're old, I say I'm sure you qualify as a fantastic mentor/teacher, besides your other qualities. Thank you sincerely.

Answer (score 0):

Apply $\ln$ to get

$$\tag 1\cot \pi x \ln x = \cos \pi x \frac{\ln x}{\sin \pi x}= \cos \pi x \frac{(\ln x-\ln 1)/(x-1)}{(\sin \pi x-\sin \pi\cdot 1)/(x-1)}.$$

As $x\to 1,\cos \pi x \to -1.$ In the fraction, use the definition of the derivative to see the top $\to \ln'(1) = 1,$ the bottom $\to$ the derivative of $\sin \pi x$ at $1,$ which is $\pi \cos \pi = - \pi.$ The limit of $(1)$ is thus $1/\pi.$ Exponentiating back gives $e^{1/\pi}$ for the original limit. (Note that the restriction $x\to 1^-$ is not needed. The full limit as $x\to 1$ is $e^{1/\pi}.$)

OK, I used the definition of the derivative and two basic derivative results. Are these not permitted here?

Comment: Sadly not permitted. I think it would work if i use that before the derivative and just change into $y=x-1$ and $y\to 0 $ and it should work.

Comment: Problems like that make no sense to me. I understand "no L'Hopital",  because it can actually hamper understanding, but not "no derivatives". $\sin x /x \to 1$ is a derivative, and is usually derived with that in mind. How do you know $\ln(1-t)/t \to -1?$

Comment: @zhw. See the comment to my answer.